# Can I store days difference of 2 columns (Start Day, End Day) into a new column in same table while creating them?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
create table Leave
(
  LeaveID int unique IDENTITY(555, 1),
  EmpID int foreign key references Employee(ID),
  From_Date date,
  To_Date date,
  **(DATEDIFF(day, From_Date, To_Date)) as Days** 
);
```

Comment: You could use computed column: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I changed your tag from MS Access to SQL Server since Access doesn't have this syntax.

Comment: Is this a column that 1) you just want to initialize once and then manually update in the future or 2) do you want it populated with the date diff every time a new row is added or From_Date or To_Date change?  If 1  then no, you'll need to create the table with empty Days values and then update after.  If 2 then use a computed column.

Answer (score 4):

Use a computed column:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Leave ADD Days AS (DATEDIFF(day, From_Date, To_Date))
```